# Why Requests per second in my vps is so low?

Tags: performance, vps

I have only build a wordpress on vps,to test the Requests per second with ab command.

```
ab -n 500 -k -c 50 http://www.mynet/
Server Software: Apache/2.4.6
Server Hostname: www.mynet
Server Port: 80

Concurrency Level: 50
Time taken for tests: 65.799 seconds
Complete requests: 500
Failed requests: 0
Non-2xx responses: 500
Keep-Alive requests: 0
Total transferred: 123500 bytes
HTML transferred: 0 bytes
Requests per second: 7.60 [#/sec] (mean)
Time per request: 6579.858 [ms] (mean)
Time per request: 131.597 [ms] (mean, across all concurrent requests)
Transfer rate: 1.83 [Kbytes/sec] received
```

I have tested for many times .
Requests per second take values from 7 till 10.
Time per request take values from 6000[ms] till 10000[ms].

The cpu and memory is below 5% as top command show.
Poor performance of vps ?

Comment: Possible reasons are bad caching setup, inefficient code, bad database design etc.

Comment: Yeah. It is simptomatic that while you mention cpu and memory you totally ignore the third bottleneck: discs. Also... Non-2xx responses: 500 - ah, that would be 100% error rate? I could be sarcastic and say you may not even connect to your website.

Answer (score 1):

WordPress is a complex piece of code, running on an interpreted language (PHP). Considering that your run your test with a high concurrency level, and that you did not mention any opcode cache, I really think your results is not too bad.

You posted way too few informations about your setup, however I strongly suspect that simply by installing zend's opcache you can improve server's performance by a significant margin.